# How to create a fn function via API?

Tags: fn

I'd like to create a fn function via API. In [the official document](http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fnproject/fn/master/docs/swagger.yml),
There are only some endpoint for creating app, routes and call.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

One of `fn contributors` answered me:

> By creating a route you would create a function with an HTTP webhook to that.